# Work Station Lock Notification

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

I am trying to write a dll which has a feature of calculating time the workstation was locked (Workstation lock as in pressing windows key + L). Now, I tried search a way for implementing this, the answer I got was listening for notifications from WTSRegisterSessionNotification. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383841%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

how can get these notifications from withing a DLL?

Example I read was :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775296%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

But couldn't understand how to use from wo=ithin a DLL.

Comment: Use it like you would in an .exe?

Comment: You need a window and a message loop to get the notification.  A DLL cannot generally assume that the main program will pump a message loop.  So you need to start a thread in your DLL that creates a hidden window and pumps a message loop.  If this all sounds like voodoo then do consider the .NET SystemEvents class if that's an option at all, it makes this trivial.